# How to retrieve all feeds of a facebook page

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

When retrieving feeds of a facebook page, we can at most get 100 feeds.
How can we parse all available feeds with graph API and node.js?
If it was recursive, we could test on paging and next elements when getting the response.

For example, this code retrieves only two last feed pages, but I want to retrieve all feeds.

```
// note: you might want to prevent the callback hell :)
graph.get('likes', {limit: 2, access_token: "foobar"}, function(err, res) {
  if(res.paging && res.paging.next) {
    graph.get(res.paging.next, function(err, res) {
      // page 2
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: give me your page name

Comment: this one : https://web.facebook.com/mosaiquefm/?fref=ts

Comment: you want output like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/DZG0o.png

Comment: i think you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a data. you must be set `user_post` permission on graph explorer.

[image]
**Code.**

```
FB.api(
  '/mosaiquefm/feed',
  'GET',
  {},
  function(response) 
  {
       // here print response. this response according to screenshot.
  }
);
```

Comment: not really. i want to iterate on next items until their starting point.